# Angular How to delete a component from ngFor Loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I read data from these child components of type custom note and i keep track of them using index, i.

```
<div *ngFor="let x of Pages; let i = index; trackBy: trackNotes">
  <app-custom-note id="inputField{{ i }}" (pagesEvent)="testUpdate($event, i)"></app-custom-note>
  <button size="small" color="danger" (click)="deletePage(i)">Delete Page</button>
</div>
<button size="small" color="success" (click)="addPage()">Add new Page</button>
```

when i click delete, i splice the elements at the parent component. but the information thats been deleted is still on the page

```
  testUpdate(card: FormGroup | FormArray, index: number) {
    let cards = new CustomPage(card.value);
    this.CustomPageEvent[index] = (cards);
  }

  trackNotes(index) {
    return index
  }

  deletePage(index) {
    this.CustomPageEvent.splice(index,1) // holds data
    this.Pages.splice(index,1) // holds length of array 
  }

  addPage() {
    this.Pages.push('A page');
    if (this.eventComponents.find(e => e.component === 'CustomNoteComponent')) {
      let orderOfPage = this.eventComponents.filter(ord => (ord.component == "CustomNoteComponent")).pop();
      this.eventComponents.push({ id: definedId, component: "CustomNoteComponent", order: addedOrder })
    }
  }
```

when `deletePage(0)` is executed, the component at index 1 is deleted. how do I delete the `<custom-component>` representational to the index `i` thats been selected?

i tried deleting by using the trackby attribute but couldnt link it to an actual delete function that deletes the component

Comment: Angular’s change detection will not be kicked off unless the reference to the object changes. Since splice only updates the existing array in place, change detection doesn’t get triggered. 

It should work if you reassign a value to your variable, something like this: `this.Pages =  this.Pages.filter((p, i) => i !== index)`

Comment: @BizzyBob cool idea, actually I worked around this by moving all the logic into the child component. Whats interesting is that i have segments of code that i do this(what i posted above) and it doesnt cause any issue. thanks for the tip ill keep it in mind to test your technique.

Comment: In my opinion, your child component looks more like a "dumb-component" (presential component). It isn't a good idea to just do it in the child component. Try to solve the issue with the idea of @BizzyBob